# Matching multiple datapoints to find a Zoho CRM module entry in Zapier

Tags: dynamics-crm, zapier, zoho

I'm working on a workflow in Zapier using the help of ChatGPT to parse emails. I've successfully extracted values from the email and now I want to create a new module entry called "Opportunity" in Zoho CRM. However, before creating the opportunity, I need to connect it to an existing module entry called "Wholesaler" in Zoho CRM.

The challenge I'm facing is that Zapier's "Find Module Entry" action allows me to search for the wholesaler by only one criteria at a time (e.g., name, email, or phone). However, to ensure that I find the right wholesaler, I need to match all three properties (name, email, and phone number) retrieved from the email.

So, my question is: How can I match the wholesaler by two or more datapoints (name, email, and phone number) in Zapier to find the correct "Wholesaler" module entry in Zoho CRM before creating the connected "Opportunity" entry?

[image: Find module entry option]

[image: There is no way to find by few criteria]

Any guidance or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I find out how to solve this problem, not ideal, but still something that we can use

> We have 3 data points that should match: name, phone and email we do
> next:
>
> 1. Searching for a module entry by name in Zoho.
> 2. Get result from Zoho and check if founded module entry email and phone number matching our data that we scrap from the email
> 3. If it match - we're good, if not, we skip the step

Still it's not perfect, because if we have 2 people with the same name (first name/last name), we could find the wrong one and we just skip the step, even if this person exist in our Zoho database.

But at lease if we found a person we 100% sure that it's the exact person we searching for.

[image]

[image]

Anyway hope Zapier make the ability to Find Module Entry by few criteria.